# How to correct the shape of Y_labels images

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, reshape

An image in GrayScale has `(H, W)` shape, although, an image RGB has `(H, W, C)` shape `(C: channels)`.

When a **Gray** image (called on the code to **DEPTH**) is loaded, I had the shape `(128, 128)` and can show this picture, with the format:

```
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [2 1 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

The same way, when an **RGB image** (called just **IMAGE**) is loaded, I had the shape `(128, 128, 3)` and can show this picture, with the format:

```
[[[21 34 27]
  [25 37 33]
  [26 37 33]
  ...
  [28 38 50]
  [18 20 20]
  [30 29 12]]
 ...
 [[20 30 33]
  [23 34 35]
  [23 35 35]
  ...
  [31 24  7]
  [34 29  1]
  [35 29  8]]]
```

How can I do to have the shape `(W, H, C)` in the Gray Image like an RGB Image?

If I reshape (using np.reshape or resize) adding just a last channel, broken the image and I can't show or use it. The image reshaped has a form `(128, 128, 1)`

```
[[[0]
  [0]
  [0]
  ...
  [0]
  [0]
  [0]]
 ...
 [[2]
  [1]
  [0]
  ...
  [0]
  [0]
  [0]]
```

---

```
Y_train = np.zeros((len(images), IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1), dtype=np.int8)
mask = np.zeros((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1), dtype=np.int8)
for i in tqdm(range(len(depths))):
&emsp;mask = imread(depths[i])
&emsp;mask = resize(mask, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), mode='constant', preserve_range=True)
&emsp;Y_train[i] = mask
print(Y_train[0].shape)
print(Y_train[0])
imshow(Y_train[0]) #-- SUCCESFULL TO PRINT
```

```
test = np.resize(test, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1))
print(test.shape)
print(test)
imshow(test) #-- FAIL TO PRINT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one on for size:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b=np.tile(a.reshape(a.shape[0],a.shape[1],1),(1,1,3))
```

results:

```
a
array([[1, 2],  
       [3, 4]])
b[:,:,0]
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
b[:,:,1]
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```